# Unversioned Javascript Google Maps API reference pulls (broken) Experimental version

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Just wanting to see if others are experiencing issues with the Google Maps API.
I am using an unversioned call to load the google maps api :

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=googleMapsLoaded&libraries=drawing,geometry,visualization,places&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

Which **should** pull in the latest **stable** api release (3.31).
As of today, it seems to be pulling in the broken experimental version (3.32)

Anyone else having this issue?
I have patched our production apps with the **v=3.31** addition to the api call for the time being.
Any feedback from others appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions), you get the experimental version if you don't specify a version (unless you are on a premium (paid) plan):

> **If you do not explicitly specify a version, you will receive the experimental version by default if you are on the standard plan** (this includes customers who do not provide a key). If you're on the premium plan and don't specify a version, you will receive the release version by default.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue myself and just discovered that specifying version 3.31 fixes the issue.  It would be nice if there was a way to specify to get the "latest stable version" rather than the latest experimental version, as now we'll have to keep on top of API versions to ensure we don't fall behind.

Comment: This is indeed the answer. The plan we are on was not what I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @BronThulke - it seems if you specify **v=3** you will get the latest **stable** release. Should save needing to deploy just to keep up with a dependency.

Comment: Thanks, yes I found this too and was relieved - should have updated my comment accordingly.